# tkinter Set focus using ID

Tags: python, linux, tkinter, focus

Python 3.3
CentOS 7

I have a number of ovals being drawn as instances to a canvas which you can click and drag on to draw a line between them. When releasing the mouse over an oval while drawing a line the end of the line needs to snap to the centre of the oval. In order for this to work you must have the oval your releasing over to be in focus or you wont trigger the button release event required to get the xy position of the oval.

I am able to get the ID of the oval using the following code

```
#get id's of items under cursor
    idList = can.find_overlapping(event.x, event.y, event.x, event.y)
    #Test if id is a anchorIn and return xy
    if len(idList) > 0:
        for items in idList:
            item = can.itemcget(items, "tag")
            for tags in item:
                if "anchorIn" in item:
                    #Get coords of anchor
                    stop = can.coords(items)
                    print(items)
                    self.stop[0] += self.anchorScale / 2
                    self.stop[1] += self.anchorScale / 2
                    #Mouse release event will not work without bringing anchor to focus
                    break
```

The problem is that there does not appear to be any way to set focus using the ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying to change the focus is not the right solution. The button release event will always fire for the widget that got the button press.

The solution is to use the canvas' [find_nearest](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.find_closest-method) method to find the canvas object nearest to the cursor.

Comment: Im not sure I understand. find_nearest returns the same thing as find_overlapping. Either one will return a list with an item ID#. I need to some way activate the instance for the item the cursor is being released over so it can store a variable with info regarding what its connected too. I left details about this out in the question as it did not seem relevant. An event handle seems to be the obvious way of achieving this outcome.